# How to add a dynamic area to a twitter bootstrap table row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement where I am using twitter bootstrap table to display user properties such as email , first name , last name , password etc.

Now i wanted to create something like in facebook account settings page. When I click on the edit button the row gets enlarge and than you can put your edit elements there in a form which has a submit button and a close button. On submitting the row again shrinks backs to the original and also on clicking the close button.

Is this possible using twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook are using a UL (unordered list) element rather than a table which is kind of better as tables are only meant to be used for displaying tabular data.

All they are doing is that when you click "edit" a hidden DIV is being populated (probably by AJAX) with the form and it's labels etc.

Then the user can either edit and save thir information which will post it back to the database or they can cancel the form which obviously unpopulates the hiddeb DIV and returns the row to it's previous state.

Bootstrap has no default programming built in for this functionality but given the basic concept above it shouldn't be too tricky for a good developer to knock up.

Answer (score 0):

Using only Bootstrap and their default JS plugins, the answer is: Nope.

You're going to need, at least, some basic JS by yourself, for replacing the cell with an input and the cell value.

There may be some jQuery plugins for this purpose also, but none I can point you.